# Each key value, join values inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a string, and I'm trying to join the content; if the val length is less than 10 chars, join it with the next value. But when i try this code, it joins with the same val instead of the next one.

```
//Set the regex.
myregex = /(<p>.*?<\/p>)/g;
//Variable string.
content =  Example: <p>Hello</p><p>This is my test content</p><p>etc</p>

$(content.match(myregex)).each(function (key, val) {
    var test = $(val).text();
    if (test.length < 10) {
        var n = val.concat(val);
        $('#mydiv').append('<div>' + n + '</div>');
    } else {
        $('#mydiv').append('<div>' + val + '</div>');
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by join it with the next value?  It would be useful to show your expected output and the current output you are getting.

Comment: Don't you need quotes around the value of `content`?

Comment: Of course, there is only one variable `val` during each iteration. Please show us the expected output, it's not entirely clear what you want to do.

Comment: @Mike Brant Expected output: //if the val is less than 10 chars: Hello This is my test content -join two values-. Actual output: //if the val is less than 10 chars: Hello Hello.

Comment: @Markasoftware I put it that way just for illustration purposes, the actual string is the one with the p tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` and `val` are the same thing, so of course `val.concat(val)` will duplicate it.

If you want to use `$.each`, I think it might be better to join with the previous value, because you don't know what the next one will be yet.

```
var previous = [];
$(content.match(myregex)).each(function (key, val) {
    var test = $(val).text();
    if (test.length < 10) {
        previous = val;
    } else {
        if(previous.length) {
            val = previous.concat(val);
        }
        $('#mydiv').append('<div>' + val + '</div>');
        previous = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: Quick follow up question, what if the joined value exceeds 20 chars, and I don't want that, how can I establish that limit?

Comment: @Aaron Instead of `if(previous.length)` you could do `if($(previous).text().length + test.length <= 20)`

Answer (score 1):

This line here:  `val.concat(val)`, is indeed duplicating your content. What you need to do is grab the next value from the `regex` instead of the current one. Something like the following should work.

```
var matches = content.match(myregex),
    myDiv = $('#mydiv');

for (var i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i++){
    if (i + 1 < len && matches[i].length < 10){
        myDiv.append('<div>' + matches[i].concat(matches[i+1]) + '</div>');
        i += 1;
    }
    else myDiv.append('<div>' + matches[i] + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I accepted the other one. Seemed more simple to me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Fair enough, but this one is probably computationally simpler as there is one less if statement and less jquery.

Comment: I know question is kinda old, but I ended up using your answer. And since I don't think it would be useful to start a new question... In this solution, how do you set a limit, so that each value doesn't exceeds let's say a 200 limit? Sorry for the inconvenience but I'm currently stuck at this. I tried this but didn't worked: if (i + 1 < len && matches[i].length < 10){
  if(matches[i].concat(matches[i+1]).length<=200){
        myDiv.append('<div>' + matches[i].concat(matches[i+1]) + '</div>');
        i += 1;}

Comment: So you've used this solution, but selected the other one as the correct answer. ;-)
It would be easier to ask another question and just reference this one, then it'd be easier to add code and for people to see the solution. But as a quick answer I'd say just use the substr function to grab up to 200 characters of the value.